# Как убрать лишние разрешения после создания билда через expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

При создании билда через `expo`, на мое приложение добавляются следующие разрешения:

- `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`
- `android.permission.CAMERA`
- `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`
- `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS`

Притом что мое приложение никак не работает с камерой, контактами и всем прочем.
Как я могу решить данную проблему, чтобы выложить приложение в google play?

Answer (score 0):

В документации описано: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/

Кратко оттуда, нужно в `AndroidManifest.xml` прописать правило `tools:node="remove"` для нужного разрешения:

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
</manifest>
```